# Doubt regarding splitting up the interval of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Consider a definite integral function $f(x)$. We know that:

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx= \int_{a}^{c}f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{b}f(x) dx$

I have a couple of conceptual doubts regarding this splitting of interval for any integral.

**Query 1:** Integral is conceptually finding the area under the curve. So, for any function when we split the area under the curve if the above statement is true then the area of the function at the value $x=c$ has to be counted exactly once, either in $\int_{a}^{c}f(x)$ or in $\int_{c}^{b}f(x)$ because if its considered in both the sums the above equation cannot be true. So, which part of these two contains the area when $x=c$? How do we prove it? Most textbooks don't seem to address this part.

**Query 2:** Is the equation above valid for ALL integrals (without exception) including: 1. Improper integral with infinity as bounds 2. Discontinuous integrals 3. Non converging integrals? I presume the answer is yes but can someone please confirm (with the argument why its true). If not what are exceptions?

Comment: The area when $x=c$ is zero

Comment: It is generally true. In the Riemann Integral case (there is more than one definition of integral) it follows from the definition as a limit of sums of disjoint trapezoidal areas.

Comment: When $x=c$ then the length is $0$ and the height is $f(c)$ so the area is $0 \times f(c) = 0$. So it's counted in both of them but it's zero so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @LanierFreeman and cyclotomicField I understand what you mean. So if I have an integral of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)$ where the function is not defined at a certain periodic values: say at .5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5.... can we split it into intervals [0, .5], [.5, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5] and so on and then add them all.. to get the original $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)$ ?

Comment: @Paul can you please clarify "It is generally true". I think (I am not sure) we mostly deal with Riemann Integrals (in textbooks and all). Does the "It" refers to the second statement being true as well (irrespective of the kind of integral as I mentioned)?

Comment: Think of it this way: the integral over $(a,b)$ is the same as the integral over $[a,b]$. That's because the area at $x=a$ and $x=b$ is zero. It's the same principle.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Thank you. I understood. Any comments on the second query. Paul seems to imply that its true as i understand but the reply isn't very clear to me?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to query 2. I was using generally in the mathematical sense meaning 'in all cases'.